Unreal Editor Standalone Window that launches an Editor Utility Widget
I'm trying to create a plugin for Unreal. I decided to go with an Editor Standalone Window as the base for my tool since I need several text inputs and a button or two.
I've been using an Editor Utility Widget to spec out the UI, but I don't know how to make use of that widget from within the Module Unreal created when I created the plugin.
There's a method in the module called "OnSpawnPluginTab":
TSharedRef<SDockTab> FGameScriptModule::OnSpawnPluginTab(const FSpawnTabArgs& SpawnTabArgs)
{
    FText WidgetText = FText::Format(
        LOCTEXT("WindowWidgetText", "Add code to {0} in {1} to override this window's contents"),
        FText::FromString(TEXT("FGameScriptModule::OnSpawnPluginTab")),
        FText::FromString(TEXT("GameScript.cpp"))
        );

    return SNew(SDockTab)
        .TabRole(ETabRole::NomadTab)
        [
            // Put your tab content here!
            SNew(SBox)
            .HAlign(HAlign_Center)
            .VAlign(VAlign_Center)
            [
                SNew(STextBlock)
                .Text(WidgetText)
            ]
        ];
}

This seems to be where the placeholder window is defined and I'm wondering how to launch my Editor Utility Widget from there.

what are you trying to do ? do you want to place your blueprint widget inside the c++ tool or do you want to launch your blueprint tool from c++ code ?
